# Correct usage of “having” + past participle

Tags: sentence-construction

One of my friends invited me in the past. I couldn't make it, so what should I say?

> 1. I am sorry for not having come.
> 2. I am sorry for not coming.

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways. Let's see the terse version.

If you couldn't go, you can simply say...

> sorry, I couldn't come.

It's good practice that you tell your friend a reason for the same.

Sorry, I couldn't make it as [ The reason]  would also work.